# Wine overrides for FONTSUB.DLL not working

Tags: wine, libraries

I have been scouring the internet for about 4 hours now and cannot get this working!

I am just trying to install Navicat Premium 11 x64 using Wine. Each time, I have ran `winecfg` and set up the library overrides for `fontsub` and have tried all settings built an native for this.

What I have tried so far:

- Following instructions on [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28651)
- Uninstalling and purging everything Wine and reinstalling
- Installing Wine Development 1.7.*
- Running from cli: `WINEDLLOVERRIDES=fontsub=n wine navicat.exe`
- Running as Root
- Banging my head against the wall

All of which product exactly the same result:

```
err:module:import_dll Loading library FONTSUB.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\PremiumSoft\\Navicat Premium\\navicat.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files\\PremiumSoft\\Navicat Premium\\navicat.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Can somebody please help as I am almost out of asprin!

Comment: Weird, the dll should be in somewhere `~/.wine`… Have you try launch it not with `wine` but with `wine64`?

Comment: @Hi-Angel I have just tried this and I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of research about the «wine dll fail» in general, together with live testing on my system shows that most probably your WINEPREFIX get screwed somehow. To check it you can simply backup it with `mv ~/.wine/ ~/.wineBCKP`, and rerun installation — now it should succeed, and the app should work. It worked for me, though I'm running *wine-1.9.1 staging*, but I think the version should be here irrelevant *(unless we're comparing with very ancient one)*.

And by the way, why do you even tackle with wine — they have GNU/Linux version as well :Ь

Comment: Thanks, I will try your method tonight. I am using wine as the download link for Navicat Premium Linux 64 is an exe! [See Here](http://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-premium?gclid=CI_lkPnYtMoCFRJwvAod0QUI1Q)

Comment: Ah, that's funny, you're right! By the way, the problem is actually only with x86-64 version, the 32 bit version link does work. Either way, it's just a little bug in their site, [I wrote them a mail about it](http://support.navicat.com/index.php?_a=tickets&_m=listview&_i=GNL-15730).

Comment: @matt1985 they just fixed the link. Interestingly, it turns out that in the archive wine libs instead of native port — although they have Mac version as well, which is POSIX compliant like GNU/Linux *(afaik the difference in graphical part, but there is GNUStep implementation)*. I guess, they implemented Mac version through Wine libs as well. Anyway, it's not so bad though — at least they do care that their app is guaranteed to work. I just don't like wine *(as opposed to native)* because there doesn't work primary selection *(middle mouse paste)* which I use a lot when I do use mouse.

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you for going through the trouble of emailing them! I don't have enough rep on the Ubuntu stack exchange to upvote your answer (maybe upvoting my question will give me enough? :-P) but you were a massive help :)